# Email will not send through VBS script

Tags: email, vbscript, outlook

I need to send a very simple email with only text to a few recipients, but I'm getting an error.

I don't have an SMTP server to send emails through, but I do have an outlook and I'm logged in through the desktop app.

Here's the script so far:

```
Set objOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set objMail = objOutlook.CreateItem(0)
objMail.Display 

objMail.to = "recipient@whatever.com"
objMail.Subject = "Test"
objMail.Body = "test"

objMail.Send

objOutlook.Quit

Set objMail = Nothing
Set objOutlook = Nothing
```

When the script is run, WSH gives the error

```
line: 10 
char:  1 
error: Operation Aborted 
source: (null)
```

This is the `objMail.Send` line.

And my outlook pops up with the proper recipient/subject/body, but it doesn't send.
I can't find anything related to this issue or a work around besides using an SMTP server which as far as I know I can't do.

Comment: Let me know if it worked for you...

Comment: Sorry about not responding. I found out that there was a firewall issue causing emails to not be sent. My script works now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a function defined and in daily use which accepts the various items for creating and sending the email.  Remember if you have to create your Outlook instance, you need to log on with the appropriate mail profile in order to send anything.  The profile we use here is just called "Outlook".  Check what yours is called and include the `Namespace` stuff I have in mine.

```
Dim sComputer : sComputer = "." ' selects local machine
Dim oWMIService : Set oWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:\\" & sComputer & "\root\cimv2")
Dim colItems : Set colItems = oWMIService.ExecQuery ("Select * from Win32_Process Where Name = 'outlook.exe'")
Dim oOutlook : Set oOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Dim oNamespace : Set oNamespace = oOutlook.GetNamespace("MAPI")
If colItems.Count = 0 Then
    LOG_Write "Outlook isn't open, logging onto it..."
    oNamespace.Logon "Outlook",,False,True ' name of Outlook profile
    bOpenedOutlook = True
End If
Dim oFolder : Set oFolder = oNamespace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
oFolder.Display ' Make Outlook visible
```

Comment: Trying to do this, but what should I set the oWMIService to in order to query the Win32_processes?

Comment: Sorry, missed out that declaration.  Edited answer.

Comment: Okay now it doesn't like the `olFolderInbox` parameter, getting `Invalid procedure call or argument: 'GetDefaultFolder'`.

Comment: I must have a constant defined for that value. I'm away from my desk now so you'll need to look up the constant on msdn or similar

Comment: FYI you can replace `olFolderInbox` with 6 or declare it as a constant and set it to 6...

Comment: I realized that a firewall was blocking emails to be sent through SMTP so I fixed it and ended up doing some more studying on Win32 scripting and got this to work as well as my original script. Putting this as the best answer as it's the only one I tried and got to work.

Answer (score 0):

Here is basic vbscript simple email

```
' For Example...
Email_List = "0m3r@Email.com;"

Set App = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set Mail = App.CreateItem(0)

With Mail
    .To = Email_List
    .CC = ""
    .BCC = ""
    .Subject = "Hello World"
    .HTMLBody = "Bla Bla!!!"
    '.Body = strbody
    'You can add a file like this
'                .Attachments.Add (FilePath)

    'use .Send (to send) or .Display (to display the email and edit before sending)
    .Display
    .send
End With

Set Mail = Nothing
Set App = Nothing
```

Save is as **`name.vbs`**